# How to run PostgreSQL without root privileges

Tags: postgresql

I want to use (or hack) the following library for unit testing PostgreSQL-based code: https://github.com/Microsoft/pgtester - this basicly starts a new server with data in temporary directory and runs all queries against it.

However, in my Linux system (Fedora 26 but quite probably other distributions as well), it cannot be used because it is difficult (or impossible) to run the server without root privileges. Namely, I am stuck at the point of creating Unix socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6433`. The directory is, by default, writable only for postgres user. On my own machine, I can of course change the writing rights but for a general-use client-side tool, it would be nice to have solution that would run out of the box.

So, is it possible to start the postgresql server with `pgctl` specifying the directory where to write the server unix socket? Or any other workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look `unix_socket_directories` at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-connection.html.

Comment: Thanks. So perhaps another stupid question - how do I pass the config value when starting the server?

Comment: You can change that in `postgresql.conf` or simply connect through TCP then you don't need a socket

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The first requires rights to edit a system file (postgresql.conf) so it's not a real solution. How would I do the second (i.e. no socket at all)?

Comment: `postgresql.conf` is part of the data directory - which needs to be owned by the user under which the Postgres process is running. If you start Postgres through `pg_ctl` from a regular user account _that_ user needs to own the data directory and thus that user also has the privileges to edit that file.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question (if you install a tool, you have the rights to modify its configuration) but see `postgres` `-c` option: "-c name=value
           Sets a named run-time parameter"

Comment: The point is imho valid - you may have access to a server with postgresql pre-installed but without admin privileges. Anyway, thanks for the `-c`